# NetSuite Migrations

Tags: mysql, db2, ibm-midrange, netsuite

Has anyone had much experience with data migration into and out of NetSuite? I have to export DB2 tables into MySQL, manipulate data, and then export ina CSV file. Then take a CSV file of accounts and manipulate the data again for accounts to match up from our old system to new. Anyone tried to do this in MySQL?

Comment: Depending on the data size you might be able to do this in Excel.  Size limits in Excel are about 1 million rows by 16k columns.  We did a migration from Intacct into NetSuite this way.  For me it's easier and faster to test changes to data, validate and troublshoot problems in Excel.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options:

1. Invest in a data transformation tool that connects to NetSuite and DB2 or MySQL. Look at Dell Boomi, IBM Cast Iron, etc. These tools allow you to connect to both systems, define the data to be extracted, perform data transformation functions and mappings and do all the inserts/updates or whatever you need to do.
2. For MySQL to NetSuite, php scripts can be written to access MySQL and NetSuite. On the NetSuite side, you can either do SOAP web services, or you can write custom REST APIs within NetSuite. SOAP is probably a bit slower than REST, but with REST, you have to write the API yourself (server side JavaScript - it's not hard, but there's a learning curve).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an IBM i programmer; try CPYTOIMPF to create a pretty generic CSV file.  I'll go to a stream file - if you have NetServer running you can map a network drive to the IFS directory or you can use FTP to get the CSV file from the IFS to another machine in your network.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adeptia's Netsuite integration tool to perform ETL. You can also try Pentaho ETL for this (As far as I know Celigo's Netsuite connector is built upon Pentaho). Also Jitterbit does have an extension for Netsuite.

Answer (score 0):

We primarily have 2 options to pump data into NS:
i)SuiteTalk ---> Using which we can have SOAP based transformations.There are 2 versions of SuiteTalk synchronous and asynchronous. 
Typical tools like Boomi/Mule/Jitterbit use synchronous SuiteTalk to pump data into NS.They also have decent editors to help you do mapping.
ii)RESTlets ---> which are typical REST based architures by NS can also be used but you may have to write external brokers to communicate with them.

Depending on your need you can have whatever you need.IN most of the cases you will be using SuiteTalk to bring in data to Netsuite.

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

We just got done doing this. We used an iPAAS platform called Jitterbit (similar to Dell Boomi). It can connect to mySql and to NetSuite and you can do transformations in the tool. I have been really impressed with the platform overall so far

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches, I like the following to process a batch job:

To import data to Netsuite:

1. Export CSV from old system and place it in Netsuite's a File Cabinet folder (Use a RESTlet or Webservices for this).
2. Run a scheduled script to load the files in the folder and update the records.
3. Don't forget to handle errors. Ways to handle errors: send email, create custom record, log to file or write to record
4. Once the file has been processed move the file to another folder or delete it.

To export data out of Netsuite:

1. Gather data and export to a CSV (You can use a saved search or similar)
2. Place CSV in File Cabinet folder.
3. From external server call webservices or RESTlet to grab new CSV files in the folder.
4. Process file.
5. Handle errors.
6. Call webservices or RESTlet to move CSV File or Delete.

You can also use Pentaho Data Integration, its free and the learning curve is not that difficult. I took [this](https://www.udemy.com/mastering-data-integration-etl-with-pentaho-kettle-pdi/) course and I was able to play around with the tool within a couple of hours.