# NetSuite Data Export 100K+ rows daily

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

I'm looking into the best solution of how to sync products (items), invoices, sales orders & customers on a daily basis. I've had other portals that sync almost 1M records in a CSV every night and run flawlessly.

Netsuite offers APIs but they all seem to be riddled with limits, and you're reliant on RESTful calls which I've found are great for a few rows, or updates, but not for when you're trying to get 100K - 1M rows.

I'm leaning towards what has worked with large sets of data and that is:

- Database connector into NetSuite (eg OBDC)
- CSV Export (somehow... I heard you can do saved searches - eg create "all customers" search, and then automate this search every night to export to a CSV)

Any help appreciated. All the NetSuite APIs look good, but I just don't see how they can handle daily sets of such large data reliably, and without hitting limits, timeouts or any of that.

---

EDIT 1: I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584292/netsuite-data-extraction-to-database) that some people pay for the (expensive) `SuiteAnalytics Connect add-on module` and got ODBC connection access to their data.

They also say you can probably do this through RESTlets and SuiteTalk but large data just won't be reliable I don't believe.

EDIT 2: Schedule saved search which sends CSV as attachment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232560/netsuite-suitescript-2-0-exportcsv) and Place CSV in File Cabinet folder. From external server call webservices or RESTlet to grab new CSV files in the folder.

EDIT 3: [NetSuite Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617294/netsuite-migrations)

EDIT 4: [netsuite suitescript 2.0 export(csv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232560/netsuite-suitescript-2-0-exportcsv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a tool for pushing csv’s from saved searches to S3.  See bundle 271853 or https://github.com/BKnights/netsuite-savedsearch-s3

It can trigger and then transfer very large results.

Once you have the data out you can use faster ETL tools to load the data into your BI system

Comment: That's private :( can't see it mate. Thats sounds perfect and exactly what I need though.

Comment: odd. I guess the customer just used the defaults when I transferred it. In the meantime I added the bundle Id. The code is all included in the bundle as well.

Comment: @Jonathan The repo is public again.

Comment: Impressive. Thanks a lot. Saves me having to write them all and can focus on the ETL

Comment: We'll be trying this in the near future, did you ever hit any limits with this script to pull CSVs with millions of rows?

Comment: I didn't while I was dealing with that but that said if you are re-posting old data you'd potentially save considerably on network costs by loading your documents and then adding new information incrementally. Do you generate millions of rows a day?

Comment: Nah needs to deal with millions of rows a day.